# How to make a right click do something different than a left click in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

This is like my first time programming so excuse the rookie question. I'm working on a project for school, in which if someone left-clicks on a picture, it adds 1 to a value in a textbox. I've already gotten that done. However, I'd like to make it so that if someone right-clicks the picturebox, it subtracts 1 from the value in the textbox. I have no clue how to do this, google isn't helping for some reason.

Is there a pretty straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: `Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick

If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
MessageBox.Show("Right button was clicked")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "right click" event, but inside all the mouse click events (click, double click, down, up) you can check the event args for which mouse button was pressed, and then use an if block to determine which set of logic gets executed. Here's an example:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        'logic to add 1 to textbox value
    ElseIf e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        'logic to subtract 1 from textbox value
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Edited** for your specific case of a picturebox:

```
Private Sub PB_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        'logic to add 1 to textbox value
    ElseIf e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        'logic to subtract 1 from textbox value
    End If
End Sub
```

*Note that this sub has *MouseEventArgs* in its arguments, and handles PictureBox1's *MouseClick* event...Those are important, as pointed out by Pro Grammer

Comment: I'm a little confused though. If I paste that if-then statement into the 'Private Sub PictureBox1_Click' thingy, it says that 'button' is not a member of 'EventArgs' and that 'Forms' is not a part of 'Windows'. I have to put that if-then statement in the code for the PictureBox1_Click, right?

Comment: You need to use `MouseClick` instead of `Click` to access `e.Button`. You can see that soohoonigan is using this event

Comment: So should I just change it from PictureBox1_Click to 'PictureBox1.MouseClick'? Also, even if I paste his code in word for word, it still says that forms isn't a part of windows.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `Windows.Forms` part. Just `MouseButtons.Left`. But yes, if you change the `Handles PictureBox1.Click` to `Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick` it should work